# Do Sobolev functions form an algebra under conventional multiplication?

Tags: real-analysis

I don't know if Sobolev functions form an algebra under conventional multiplication. If you define a Sobolev space say $W^{1,1},$ then we have completeness under a sum of norms of first partial derivatives.

If you take a function $f(x,y)$ and another $g(x,y)$ and the partial derivatives of both exist, $\partial_x, \partial_y,$ then is it necessarily true that any product of sums of $f$ and $g$ is also partially differentiable in the same way, or otherwise, also an element of the same space?

Comment: No they don't form an algebra in general.  Yes product of differentiables are differentiables (recall product rule for derivatives).  The problem is with the finiteness of the $L^p$-norms.

Comment: I'm sure there's a subtlety here, but at a glace it looks like you just contradicted yourself. The product of two partially differentiable functions is partially differentiable, okay, but are you perhaps trying to suggest they are unbounded under the Sobolev norm in some way? If the product of $f$ and $g$ is also partially differentiable, can you expand on what the problem is, because otherwise, why wouldn't they form an algebra?

Comment: Yes, I am saying you can get $\lVert fg\rVert_p=\infty$ even if $\lVert f\rVert_p,\lVert g\rVert_p<\infty$ ($p\neq\infty$).  That is without even thinking of the derivatives.

Comment: That's an interesting result, thank you for sharing it. Do you perhaps have a reference for that, or otherwise are there examples where one might be able to easily prove this is the case?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have seen this before: $f\colon x\mapsto x^\alpha$ is in $L^p(0,1)$ iff $\alpha>-p^{-1}$.  But there is no reason why $2\alpha>-p^{-1}$, required for $f\cdot f\in L^p$.

Comment: I should also mention there are cases when they form an algebra.  See e.g. Theorem A.1 in [here](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/arkiv-for-matematik/volume-59/issue-2/Multiplication-in-Sobolev-spaces-revisited/10.4310/ARKIV.2021.v59.n2.a2.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$W^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ forms an algebra wrt multiplication if $sp>d$ for $p\in(1,\infty)$ or $p=1$ and $s=d$. This follows from the inequality $$\|fg\|_{s,p}\leq\|f\|_\infty\|g\|_{s,p}+\|g\|_\infty\|f\|_{s,p}$$ and the Sobolev Embedding Theorem.

Comment: Thank you for that result, so it appears that the answer is dependent on the specific choice of the order of the derivatives, the norm and the domain space.

Comment: wait, hold up, does that mean user10354138 was incorrect and mislead me? If the second part of your first sentence is true, then $W_{1,1}$ does form an algebra, contrary to what the other user suggested.

Comment: Only over $\mathbb{R}$ and not in any higher dimension. Son in particular not with functions of two variables as you seemed interested in.

Comment: I see, I think, thank you for clarifying. So for instance if we have a function $f(x,y)$ which is a map from $\mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ then $W_{1,1}$ does not form an algebra.